# MySQL command line: how to store values?

Tags: mysql, bash

Let's say I do

```
select invoice_id from table where country = 'it';
```

I get a bunch of ID's, which I would like to store for a second in an array called invoices

Then I want to do something like

```
select email from table2 where invoice_id in invoices;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Does that not provide you the emails that have matching invoice_id's. Or are you doing something else?

```
select
t2.email
from table t
join table2 t2
on t.invoice_id = t2.invoice_id
where t.country = 'it';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of "arrays" when using SQL, think of "result sets".  What you want to do is to return a one-column result set from your first query, and use it as a subquery in your second one:

`select email from table2 where invoice_id in (select invoice_id from table where country = 'it');`